# How would I make this into an dynamic :nth-child css selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm working on a diamond grid system with CSS, and I need to move the 5th block, and then the 12th, 19th, 26th and so on to the left. How could I make this into a dynamic nth selector?

```
.diamond-grid > div:nth-child(26),
.diamond-grid > div:nth-child(19),
.diamond-grid > div:nth-child(12),
.diamond-grid > div:nth-child(5) {
    margin-left: 182px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution can you find here: https://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

In your situation, I think you need is `:nth:child(7n+5){  }`

**Explanation:**

`7n` are the steps you have to set, `5` is the starting element.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I've look at the CSS-Tricks article as well, but couldn't figure it out. Maybe I wasn't paying attention well enough.

Comment: @AndorNagy I don't think it's up to *attention* as much as it is *effort*

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
.diamond-grid > div:nth-child(7n+5){
    margin-left: 182px;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, Frank, and thanks for contributing!

Answer (score 4):

Since you're selecting every 7th element starting from the 5th element, use `:nth-child(7n + 5)`:

```
.diamond-grid > div:nth-child(7n + 5) {
  margin-left: 182px;
}
```

If you want to start at the 26th element and select every previous 7th element:

```
.diamond-grid > div:nth-child(-7n + 26) {
  margin-left: 182px;
}
```

Comment: I just found an old answer of mine with literally [the exact same expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732923/css-nth-child-formula-to-select-every-7th-element-and-the-5th-element/10732981#10732981) as your first.

Comment: @BoltClock Ha, sounds like an exact duplicate. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Well other than stopping at the 26th element anyway...